# asciidoctor: how to reference attribute from link macro

Tags: asciidoctor

How can I reference a custom attribute when using the link macro?

I have "my_attribute" set to (eg) "http://example.com"

This **does not work** - produces <a href="{my_attribute}"...

```
link:{my_attribute}[Example Link,window="_blank"].
```

This **does not work** - {my_attribute} is expanded but the entire link macro is not expanded:

```
[subs="attributes,macros"]
----
link:{my_attribute}[Example Link,window="_blank"].
----
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, reversing the order of subs fixed this!

```
[subs="macros,attributes"]
----
link:{my_attribute}[Example Link,window="_blank"].
----
```

well, there you go